# data is not submitted to database using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php and MySQL. When I submit the form data is not stored in the database table 'plantation_journal_nursery_details'.  I am badly stuck here. Can anyone please advice me that how can I solve this problem?? Thanks in advance guys. codes are given below :

create_journal.php

```
<form action="data_fetch.php" action="post">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <h4 style="font-size: 16px;padding-left: 15px;"><b>Nursery Location:</b></h4><br>
                                <div align="right" style="padding-right: 10px;">
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">Location:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="location" id="location" style="width:50%;height: 30px; margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 5px;"><br>
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">Area:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="area1" id="area1" style="width:50%;height: 30px; margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 5px;"><br>
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">type of Nursey:</label>
                                    <select  name="type_of_nursery" id="type_of_nursery" style="width:50%;height: 30px; margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 5px;">
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                    </select><br><br>
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">Centranl Nursery Name:</label>
                                    <select  name="central_nursery_name" id="central_nursery_name" style="width:40%;height: 30px; margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 5px;">
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                    </select><br><br>
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">State Nursery Name:</label>
                                    <input type="text"  name="state_nursery_name" id="state_nursery_name"  style="width:50%;height: 30px; margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 5px;"><br>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <h4 style="font-size: 16px;padding-left: 15px;"><b>Size of Each Bed:</b></h4><br>
                                <div align="right" style="padding-right: 10px;">
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">Mother Bed Size:</label>
                                    <input type="text"  name="mother_bed_size" id="mother_bed_size"  style="width:50%;height: 30px; margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 5px;"><br>
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">Quantity:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="quantity_m" id="quantity_m" style="width:50%;height: 30px; margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 5px;"><br><br><br>
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">Source of Seed:</label>
                                    <select name="source_of_seed" id="source_of_seed" style="width:50%;height: 30px; margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 5px;">
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                    </select><br><br>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div align="right" style="padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 40px">
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">Polypot Bed Size:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="polypot_bed_size" id="polypot_bed_size" style="width:42%;height: 30px; margin-left: 4px; border-radius: 5px;"><br>
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">Quantity:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="quantity_p" id="quantity_p" style="width:42%;height: 30px; margin-left: 4px; border-radius: 5px;"><br><br>
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">Hycopot Bed Size:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="hycopot_bed_size" id="hycopot_bed_size" style="width:42%;height: 30px; margin-left: 4px; border-radius: 5px;"><br>
                                    <label style="font-weight:300;font-size: 15px">Quantity:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="quantity_h" id="quantity_h" style="width:42%;height: 30px; margin-left: 4px; border-radius: 5px;"><br>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div align="right" style="padding-right: 10px;">
                                <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="submit16" value="Add" onclick="move7()">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

data_fetch.php

```
    <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","forestdb");
    if(isset($_POST['submit16'])){
    $location=$_POST['location'];
    $area1=$_POST['area1'];
    $type_of_nursery=$_POST['type_of_nursery'];
    $central_nursery_name=$_POST['central_nursery_name'];
    $state_nursery_name=$_POST['state_nursery_name'];
    $mother_bed_size=$_POST['mother_bed_size'];
    $quantity_m=$_POST['quantity_m'];
    $source_of_seed=$_POST['source_of_seed'];
    $polypot_bed_size=$_POST['polypot_bed_size'];
    $quantity_p=$_POST['quantity_p'];
    $hycopot_bed_size=$_POST['hycopot_bed_size'];
    $quantity_h=$_POST['quantity_h'];


    $query="SELECT plantation_journal_no from plantation_journal_basic_details where plantation_journal_no=(select max(plantation_journal_no) from plantation_journal_basic_details);";
    $res=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    $plantation_journal_no=$row['plantation_journal_no'];
    $sql="INSERT INTO `plantation_journal_nursery_details`(`plantation_journal_no`, `location`, `area`, `type_of_nursery`, `central_nursery_name`, `state_nursery_name`, `mother_bed_size`, `quantity`, `source_of_seed`, `polypot_bed_size`, `quantity_p`, `hycopot_bed_size`, `quantity_h`) VALUES ('$plantation_journal_no','$location','$area1','$type_of_nursery','$central_nursery_name','$central_nursery_name','$mother_bed_size','$quantity_m','$source_of_seed','$polypot_bed_size','$quantity_p','$hycopot_bed_size','$quantity_h');";

    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if($result){
        echo "<script>alert('data submitted.');</script>";
        header("Location:create_journal.php");
    }
}

?>
```

[image: Frontend Table]

[image: Backend Table]

Comment: Check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) after you run your query. Additionally, You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: You are having two `action` attribute in form. `action="data_fetch.php" action="post"` the second one should be `method="post"`

Comment: Images of a schema aren't very useful. We can't copy/paste the column/table names. I also agree with the comment from @aynber about SQL Injection and the quoting issues. Be sure to edit your question and post the full text of any error messages

Comment: The select appears to be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Your insert query, before you edited your question, contained ...

```
...VALUES ('$plantation_journal_no',$configurarion','$slope','$water_table_in_...
```

Notice that your single quotes aren't matched.  You should have

```
...VALUES ('$plantation_journal_no','$configurarion','$slope','$water_table_in_...
```

If you had checked for an error in your query you would have found this problem immediately. Code like this would have helped.

```
if($result){
    echo "<script>alert('data submitted.');</script>";
    header("Location:create_journal.php");
}
else {
    die  $mysqli->error;
}
```

**Pro tip**: Format your code so you don't have to scroll horizontally to see entire queries. It's far easier to examine your queries and find mistakes that way. You can use [php's **heredoc** syntax for string constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to do that.

This is how it looks.

```
    $sql= <<<INSERTQUERY
INSERT INTO `plantation_journal_nursery_details`
       (`plantation_journal_no`, `location`, `area`, `type_of_nursery`, 
        `central_nursery_name`, `state_nursery_name`, `mother_bed_size`, 
        `quantity`, `source_of_seed`, `polypot_bed_size`, `quantity_p`, 
        `hycopot_bed_size`, `quantity_h`) 
  VALUES 
       ('$plantation_journal_no','$location','$area1','$type_of_nursery',
        '$central_nursery_name','$central_nursery_name','$mother_bed_size',
        '$quantity_m','$source_of_seed','$polypot_bed_size','$quantity_p',
        '$hycopot_bed_size','$quantity_h');
INSERTQUERY;
```

Comment: You also should use bind variables. But you didn't ask about that.

Comment: No, but it's pretty fundamental.